# Problems writing to an XML file in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

I created a client-server restaurant project in which I read from an XML file. But I need to write and update the XML file. I faced a lot of problem when I write XML .
I searched various websites and forums, but I could not found any solutions. Please help me if anyone knows how to do this.

I wrote the following code to create a sample project which I found from a tutorial.
But some errors occur when I build:

> Error:NSXMLDocument , NSXmlNode  undeclared

I tried adding the Cocoa framework to solve this, but it didn't seem to work.

```
- (NSData *)constructXMLRequest
{
    NSXMLElement *root = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"Request"];
    [root addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"Attribute1" stringValue:@"Value1"]];
    [root addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"Attribute2" stringValue:@"Value2"]];
    [root addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"Attribute3" stringValue:@"Value3"]];

    NSXMLElement *childElement1 = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"ChildElement1"];
    [root addChild:childElement1];
    [childElement1 release];

    NSXMLElement *childElement2 = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"ChildElement2"];
    [childElement2 addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"ChildAttribute2.1" stringValue:@"Value2.1"]];
    [childElement2 setStringValue:@"ChildValue2.1"];
    [root addChild:childElement2];
    [childElement2 release];

    NSXMLDocument *xmlRequest = [NSXMLDocument documentWithRootElement:root];
    [root release];
    NSLog(@"XML Document\n%@", xmlRequest);
    return [xmlRequest XMLData];
}
```

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but might help someone.

`<Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` is not supported in iOS.

C out [KissXML](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML). Add it to your project, and just change the `NSXMLElement` to `DDXMLElement` in the above code.

Comment: Thank you! And it should be mentioned, that it's not even necessary to rename classes, because KissXML's standart header #defined NSXMLElement as DDXMLElement (etc.) if the platform is iOS.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't cover full NSXML API though.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't even have `documentWithRootElement ` method. Possible solution to avoid it https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kissxml/MZ18szX_U8o

Answer (score 0):

Here is Sample code in iOS Reference Library.

[SeismicXML](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html)

[XMLPerformance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html)